# access assets folder using a component url parameter

Tags: vue.js

I have a component that takes an image url as parameter. Within my component I use this url as an image path

```
<img :src="imgUrl" />
```

I consume this component using

```
<MyComponent imgUrl="@/assets/images/logo.png" />
```

When passing this parameter the image file is not found. I tried multiple ways and provide an example

https://codesandbox.io/s/6zmj1q5ypr

What needs to get fixed?

I don't know if this is important but I created my app with the Vue CLI so I use webpack

Answer (score 2):

Try importing in in your script and setting it as a data property then passing the data property in as the `imgUrl`.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <my-component :imgUrl="image" />
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent.vue'
import image from '@/assets/logo.png'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    MyComponent
  },
  data() {
    return { image }
  }
}
</script>
```

You'll need to bind it to the property so make sure to precede `imgUrl` with `:`.

Comment: import image from '@/assets/logo.png'
 will not work as I know. the image can't be included with JS file ,except the base64 trick.

Comment: @MosheL, `webpack` will handle this on compile. Please clone [THIS REPO](https://github.com/CoryKleiser/webpack-vue-example) and follow `README.md` instructions. Thanks

Comment: You saved my day. I did not find any other way to return images as parameters in data() and letting vue to check the assets (like `require` did in 2.x)

Comment: @avtomaton glad my answer helped you out. Maybe consider throwing me an upvote ;)